# Categorical or Categorial? Is there a difference between the two terms from a statistician's point of view?

Tags: categorical-data, inference, descriptive-statistics, terminology, binary-data

I have heard about Categorical distribution and Categorical variables in statistics. But what is a Categorial variable? Can both Categorial and Categorical be used interchangeably? Are there specific cases in which we use either of these terms?

Comment: "Categorial" is a common typographical error (especially among non-native English writers).  Right up there in frequency is "binominal" (a technical term in other fields that is wholly absent in statistical literature) for "binomial."

Comment: _Categorial_ is also used in philosophy, as witness Stephan Körner's book _Categorial Frameworks_. To the point, this is misquoted by Wikipedia as _Categorical_. But I agree: the term _categorical_ is utterly standard in statistics for this meaning.

Comment: *Categorial* is uncommon, but still too common to be solely a typographic or an idiosyncratic error. (I've never seen *historial* or the like.) It must have some currency as a variant form of *categorical* in English; or in another language, in which perhaps analogues of *categorical* & *categorial* have more distinct senses.

Comment: Ah! .... *kategorische* in German corresponds to *categorical* in the sense of "absolute", "unconditional", or "unqualified"; *kategorial* to *categorical* in the sense we're here concerned with. So https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategoriale_Variable. In French there seems to be a similar distinction between *catégorique* & *catégoriel* - https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_cat%C3%A9gorielle.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica, that's an interesting observation. The speaker was German and maybe that's a problem with the language. In English too, the word Catergorical can mean "absolute" or "unconditional". Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Aadi: Yes - *categorial* even sometimes makes it into published work - [Gertheiss & Tutz (2010), "Sparse modeling of categorial variables", *Ann. App. Stat.*, **4**, 4](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-statistics/volume-4/issue-4/Sparse-modeling-of-categorial-explanatoryvariables/10.1214/10-AOAS355.full). That's not a typo in the title - the authors are from Munich University & use *categorial* throughout the paper.

Answer (score 16):

I have literally never heard '*categorial*' (without the second C) and assumed that this was a typo. But some googling does indicate that [this word is used - in linguistics](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/categorial#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20categorial,a%20priori%20a%20categorial%20system).

In statistics, as far as I know, we only use *categori**c**al*.

As mild support for this claim, if one googles 'categorial statistics', Google assumes you've made a typo and [returns only results for 'categori**c**al statistics'](https://www.google.com/search?q=categorial+statistics&ei=H2i9YpGVI4btkgWl1ZngAQ&ved=0ahUKEwjRoK_w6dT4AhWGtqQKHaVqBhwQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=categorial+statistics&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEAoyBAgAEAoyBAgAEAoyBAgAEAoyBAgAEAoyCAgAEB4QCBAKMggIABAeEAgQCjoHCAAQRxCwAzoHCAAQsAMQQzoECAAQQzoFCAAQgAQ6BAgAEB46BggAEB4QCkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFDxB1j8OWDRP2gBcAF4AIABP4gBxQOSAQE4mAEAoAEByAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz).

Also, searching for 'categorial' on wikipedia returns no links, but the closest suggestion is ['categorial grammar'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorial_grammar) (again, about language/syntax). In contrast, searching for 'categori**c**al' returns [a bunch of suggestions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical) including several articles about statistics (specifically [categorical data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable)), maths and logic.

EDIT: [This excellent comment by Scortchi](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/580525/categorical-or-categorial-is-there-a-difference-between-the-two-terms-from-a-st/580526?noredirect=1#comment1072122_580525) may have tracked down the origin of the confusion to German and French distinctions that are mostly absent in English.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I recently saw someone using 'Catergorial variables' while talking about Loss functions. Also, both words seem to be having the same meaning. 'Categorical' seem to be more prominent in the web.

Comment: Second. In math I've never seen "Catergorial". I think in English that word is almost never used.

Comment: Yeah but please don't use Google typo suggestions as evidence, however mild, for anything.

Answer (score 5):

I second mkt's answer; this is a long comment rather than an answer. In math I've never seen "Categorial".

Also, I think in English that word is rarely used. The frequency is about 20 times less than the proper word "categorical"
[image]

I asked a question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/318157/) and English experts will surely help us.